# Compare two strings in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, test

My script needs two arguments. I want to hide the error message if someone calls the script with

```
script.sh --help
```

so I tired this:

```
if [ $# -ne 2 ] ; then
  if [ "$1" -ne "--help" ]; then
    echo "ERROR: wrong number of parameters"
    echo
  fi
  echo "Syntax: $0 foo bar
  exit 1
fi
```

But I get the error

```
script.sh: line 10: [: --help: integer expression expected
```

What is wrong?

Comment: You are using `-ne`, which is for integer comparison. Just use `[ ! "$1" == "--help" ]` instead

Answer (score 1):

the parameter `-ne` is only valid for numbers, you have to use `!=` for string comparism.

This works:

```
if [ $# -ne 2 ] ; then
  if [ "$1" != "--help" ]; then
    echo "ERROR: wrong number of parameters"
    echo
  fi
  echo "Syntax: $0 foo bar
  exit 1
fi
```